# java collections framework - reading input and outputting lines floor(n/2),...,n-1

Tags: java, list, collections

So I'm trying to learn java and I've been given some code and a task of questions to complete by editing the given code. I'm stumped about one question in particular because I don't understand at all what it's asking me to do. I was wondering if I could get some help or a push in the right direction. Any links to resources that would help me would also be really appreciated.

Read the input one line at a time until you have read all n lines and imagine these lines are numbered 0,...,n-1. Next output lines floor(n/2),...,n-1 followed by lines 0,..,.floor(n/2)-1.

This is the main part of the code I'm given but the rest of it can be found here: https://pastebin.com/4ZatEat8

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            BufferedReader r;
            PrintWriter w;
            if (args.length == 0) {
                r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                w = new PrintWriter(System.out);
            } else if (args.length == 1) {
                r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
                w = new PrintWriter(System.out);               
            } else {
                r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
                w = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(args[1]));
            }
            long start = System.nanoTime();
            doIt(r, w);
            w.flush();
            long stop = System.nanoTime();
            System.out.println("Execution time: " + 10e-9 * (stop-start));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there something in particular you're confused about?

Comment: HINT: The basic task here is to 1) read and remember a bunch of lines; 2) divide the bunch up into first and second halves; 3) print the second half; 4) print the first half.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it wants you to read a whole file first and then print the lines in specific asked order.

Let's take an example, Suppose you have a temp.txt file with 5 lines like below:

> A
>
> B
>
> C
>
> D
>
> E

Now, you need to read all the lines of this temp.txt. You can create an ArrayList object of lines. Since a list starts from 0, It will automatically satisfy the condition that line should be number from 0. Then it wants you to print the lines in a specific order.

For our example, **n=5**

First, they want output line no with  **floor(n/2),...,n-1**

So your output would be like below,

> C
>
> D
>
> E

The reason is that floor(n/2) = floor(5/2) = 2. So start from line 2 to n-1 which is 4 (5-1) . Same way, next it wants you to print **0,..,.floor(n/2)-1**. So line no 0 to 1.
So,

> A
>
> B

The final output would be like,

> C
>
> D
>
> E
>
> A
>
> B

If you want to learn more about the collection and file IO operation you can refer to [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/index.htm).